# How to send user to wordpress dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I created a new user and i gave him “author” role. I want him to only can write posts in wordpress. But when he logs in, he enters the user profile but not wordpress dashboard which is where i want. How can i fix this? I want him to go to wordpress dashboard so he can write posts only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
  // check if current user is the post author
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  {
     wp_redirect( admin_url( 'the url you need to redirect' ) );
     exit;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Should i put it in functions.php?

Comment: Hi, i putted the code in functions.php, i receive a warning which says: “ cannot modify headers information-headers already sent by (an address which ends with functions.php where i putted the function). I putted the code.

Comment: I tried putting the code before, inside the codes and after the codes, same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
function check_custom_authentication () {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
    $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

    if ( in_array('author', $user_roles, true ) ) {
        wp_redirect(admin_url());
        exit;
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_login' , 'check_custom_authentication' );
```